# リピーターとブリッジによるセグメントの分断

Tags: network

## 概要

マスタリングTCP/IPを呼んでいたのですが、その過程で以下の記述を見かけました。

> ネットワークをブリッジで接続するとセグメントが２つに分割されるが、
> リピーターで接続するとセグメントは１つになる

出典

> 目次 > データリンク > データリンクの役割 > データリンクのセグメント

しかしこれには納得できない部分があります。
以下に現状理解していることと、疑問点を記載しました。

理解が浅く、わかりにくい質問となってしまい申し訳ありません。

## 理解していること

### リピーターの機能

- ネットワーク同士を接続する
- 弱った信号を増強する

### ブリッジの機能

- ネットワーク同士を接続する
- 流れてくるMACアドレスを学習し、それぞれのセグメントに属するMACアドレスを記憶する

### リピーターで繋いだ場合

- 物理層から見ると２つのセグメント
- ネットワーク層から見ると１つのセグメント

### ブリッジで繋いだ場合

- 物理層から見ると２つのセグメント
- ネットワーク層から見ても２つのセグメント

## 疑問

リピーターはただ弱った信号を強化するだけのものなので、ネットワーク層においてセグメントを分ける機能がないというのは直感的に理解できます。

しかし、**ブリッジで接続するとセグメントが分割される**という箇所が理解できません。

ブリッジとてリピーターと同じくネットワーク同士を接続するものであるという点で似ています。
**セグメントを分ける**という機能は何によってもたらされているのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(回答重複してそうだけどとりあえず書いたので)

リピーターとは名前の通り増幅器です。
物理的に離れたところにあるノードと通信行う場合ケーブルの仕様などあり 信号が減衰してしまう
ケーブルの信号をリピーターによって信号増幅し繋げてしまう, ので, 同一ネットワークであり低レイヤーの話

ブリッジも名前の通り橋渡しです。
例えば Ethernetと Wi-Fiとを接続し, パケットを橋渡しする, など。Ethernetとそれ以外もあるし, あるいは Ethernet同士のことも (Ethernet以外と Ethernet以外の場合も当然含まれる)
MACアドレスにより受け取り, そのフレームを交換(渡す先の物理ネットワークでの MACアドレスへ)
なので比較的低レイヤーだけどリピーターよりは上のレイヤー
もちろん物理的に違うネットワーク

---

##### 追記

他の質問([ネットワーク全体の情報を取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85168/)) の回答にもあるように, データリンク層(Layer2) Ethernetプロトコルでは物理的に繋がっていない(直接送り届けるのがムリ) なら, Layer2 以下を使って直接送り届けるのは不可能。

上位層のネットワーク層(Layer3) であれば, 論理アドレス(IPアドレス) を使い, ルーターなどを経由して (そっちで頼むね, と) 送り届けることが可能

ブリッジはその中間的な位置で, MACアドレスを認識し, フレーム交換することで(直接繋がっていないけれど) 送り届けることが可能
(物理的に別ネットワークなので, 「セグメント」)

Answer (score 3):

なぜと問われても「セグメントを分ける機器をブリッジと呼ぶことにした」のだからそれ以上の理由はないっス。

Answer (score 2):

注目する点や考え方の方向性が違うので理解しにくいのだと思われます。

「ブリッジで接続するとセグメントが分割される」と書くとセグメントが受け身な風に捉えられますが、先に行う/決定するのはコンピュータ等ネットワークを利用する機器の配置と、それらを接続するネットワーク構成を設計することで、その中には「セグメントを分ける」ことも含まれます。そして、それらは担当する人間が積極的/主体的に行います。

そして「分けたセグメントを接続する必要がある」からそこにブリッジ(機能を持つ機器)を置くわけです。

セグメントを分ける「機能」とかリピータやブリッジという「機器の機能」だけに注目するのではなく、「セグメント」やそれを「同じにする/分ける/接続する」というのはどのような物/状態か、それぞれの「メリット/デメリット」は何かといったことも視野に入れて学んでみてください。

---

と言う風にちょっと注釈を入れたところで回答＋αとしては以下になるでしょう。

- 「ブリッジで接続するとセグメントが分割される」とか「ブリッジとてリピーターと同じくネットワーク同士を接続するものである」という記述に注目するよりも、ネットワーク上の機器の配置やそれらの接続/構成は、先ず「人間が設計して構築するものである」という点を前提に考えてください。
- あと細かいことですがこの質問内容の場合「ブリッジとてリピーターと同じくネットワーク同士を接続するものである」の中で「ネットワーク同士」と言うよりも「セグメント同士」と記述する方が相応しいと思われます。
- 「セグメントを分けるという機能は何によってもたらされているか」という聞き方に対しては、トートロジー的になりますが「セグメントを分けるという機能を持った(or仕様を実装している)機器とその設定情報」によってもたらされている、と言えるでしょう。@774RR さんの回答と同様な感じです。
- もう少し具体的な何かを示すとなると、下記参考記事例の中の「スパニングツリープロトコル」とその関連の記事・情報でしょうか。
- 上記最初の「人間が設計して構築するものである」点で考えると「ネットワークが混雑しないように、かつセキュリティの設定・管理がしやすくなるように」と言う基準/目的を掲げて、「セグメントを分割する設計を行う」ことによってもたらされているというのが先にきて、その設計に従って「セグメントを分けるがネットワークとしての接続は行う機能を持った機器」が導入・設置されることになるでしょう。

---

参考記事例：
[リピータ 【repeater】](https://e-words.jp/w/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF.html)
[ブリッジ 【bridge】](https://e-words.jp/w/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8.html)
[ネットワークセグメント 【network segment】 LANセグメント / LAN segment](https://e-words.jp/w/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88.html)
[コリジョンドメイン 【collision domain】 衝突ドメイン](https://e-words.jp/w/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3.html)
[ブロードキャストドメイン 【broadcast domain】](https://e-words.jp/w/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3.html)

[こっそり聞きたいネットワークのキホン（第23回）ネットワークを分割して安全性・利便性を高める](https://bizdrive.ntt-east.co.jp/articles/dr00101-023.html)
[LANセグメントを分ける仮想LAN、VLANのお話](https://ponsuke-tarou.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/03/12/233508)
[VLANでネットワークを分割するメリットとは？](https://xtech.nikkei.com/atcl/nxt/column/18/00131/020600001/)
[家庭内LANのセグメント分けとは？わかりやすく解説](https://www.panduit.co.jp/column/naruhodo/4289/)

[ブリッジ (ネットワーク機器) - Wikipeida](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8_(%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E6%A9%9F%E5%99%A8))
[ブリッジ接続 - Wikipeida](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A)
[スパニングツリープロトコル - Wikipeida](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%91%E3%83%8B%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%84%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB)
[ネットワークの基礎講座 IP（インターネット・プロトコル） ブリッジ、ルータ、ゲートウエイ](https://www.cresc.co.jp/tech/network/NET_TUTORIAL/Section_304.htm)